# PHP is ignoring my HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php

i created a login and signup system with files like : 
`register.php` action for the form is `do_register.php`
`login.php` action for the form is `do_login.php`
and i don't want the user to access the `do_register.php` or the `do_login.php` only if they are redirected by `register.php` or `login.php`.
so i though about bloking access via HTTP_REFERER here is the lines:

```
$refer=$_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($refer!= "http://www.example.com/register.php")
{
header("location:index.php");
}
```

but the problem that it is not blocking the access .

Comment: What's the value of `$refer`?

Comment: $refer=$_SERVER ['HTTP_REFERER'];

Comment: Stop. You can't depend on `referer`. Throw this code out and use nonce based CSRF protection instead.

Comment: Thats a value assignment. But not a value. Do `var_dump($referer)`.

Comment: @Quentin : I'm noob at this.

Comment: It's a bad idea because you can simple change or disable the browser HTTP referer. I would use `$_SESSION` instead and assign true or false to that variable.

Comment: @omeinusch — So? You have some useful keywords with which to find tutorials using Google now.

Comment: @Quentin ? :( ... what do you mean? :(

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=nonce+csrf

Comment: thank you guys , i think  `$_POST['submit']` checking will do the refer , and i'll do some token things .. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the referer to do this sort of check. Rather make a condition on the POST fields. I assume you have a submit button. Rather check with

```
if ($_POST['submitbutton_name'])
```

It is a very common way to do this.

So the full code would be:

```
if(!$_POST['submitbutton_name']) {
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: and always make `die();` after calling header with location argument

Comment: or exit(); ;) I was finishing my answer but of course :)

Comment: Yeah that's the sollution , i already was using it if the action is on the same file .. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome thanks :) Any chance to get an up vote too? :P

Comment: I'm still new here sorry.